# How do I set windows to floating by default without them resetting to floating when I reload config?

Tags: i3-window-manager

I have this neat rule in my i3 config file:

```
# Set floating by default
for_window [class="[.]*"] floating enable
```

All windows are now floating by default when they first open. I think this is great. Most windows I open I just need temporarily and I don't want them to interfere with my carefully organized layout.

The problem is: when I make a change to my i3 config and reload it using the `reload` command (bound to `$mod+Shift+c` in my case) all my open windows reset to floating. They don't do so immediately, but as soon as I interact with them they pop out. This is super frustrating considering how long it takes to organize my window layout.

Is it possible to have windows floating by default and prevent them from resetting to floating when I reload my config? If it's also possible to have them remain stacked when restarting i3 (`restart`/`$mod+Shift+r`) that would be amazing.

---

I vaguely remember reading somewhere that windows can be marked/flagged in the i3 config, and I think that can be used to ensure that an operation is performed just once for a window. I hope that flag doesn't reset when reloading i3. I'm going to look into that further, but I'm adding this question here just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking i3 layout saving.

https://i3wm.org/docs/layout-saving.html

Comment: I have used that for some things, but it doensn't answer my question in any way. I organize my windows across workspaces based on what applications I'm using. A static encoded layout in a JSON file isn't good enough. Or are you suggesting saving the current layout temporarily when reloading i3, then loading the layout after? In that case I'm going to need more details on how to do that :P

Comment: My suggestion was based in that you create a script which saves all your workspaces, and one which loads all your workspaces. Then you can auto call them on reload or bind some keys. Although it was probably hard to tell ;)